# Asp.Net Web Forms Bundling of jQuery libraries

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bundle, config

I have a Web Forms application where I am struggling to get jquery bundling to work properly.

I have tried multiple variations of the following code and I have also tried to use the NuGet package [AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery/), but nothing has worked so far.

The problem is that the script seems to be downloaded on client side, but it doesn't work:

[image: jquery bundle loaded]
When a jquery function is called, I get the typical "TypeError: **$(...).is not a function**"-error.

My code in BundleConfig.cs:

```
 BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"));
 ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery",
            new ScriptResourceDefinition
            {
                Path = "~/bundles/jquery",
                DebugPath = "~/bundles/jquery",
            });
```

And in Site.Master:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/GlobalFunctions5.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/AjaxControlToolkit/Bundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Ultimately, I want to be able to upgrade the jQuery NuGet packages without having to change the BundleConfig, so I tried this as well (which doesn't even load the bunde on client side):

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Is there anything that might also impact bundling jQuery or what did I get wrong here?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" the issue by starting a new Web Forms project and moving all contents there. This has resolved the issue. Part of the problem might have been that the original project was created with VS 2008 and for the new project I used VS 2015.
I did not change the Web Forms template and simply added the NuGet packages AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery and AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined. Now bundling and minification with jQuery is working properly, but the drawback and updating jQuery still requires some more manual interaction persists.